# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select on word seperator?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a keybinding to enable navigating and selecting text based half word boundary or separators. Consider the variable:

```
a_reallyLong_variable_name
```

Assuming cursor is at the beginning of the variable, then using a keybinding, I would like to select 'a_' on first press, 'a_really' on second press, 'a_reallyLong_' on third press and so on.

I'm running VS Code on Windows 10 and I regularly remote into Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VS Code keybindings and search for "wordPart" and then add the keybindings as per your liking.
I'm using the following:

[image: Vs Code Keybindings for Word Part or Word Boundary]

The **Alt+LeftArrow** and **Alt+RightArrow** were already in use so I removed those because I was not using it often.